# CSS and Images on Heroku broken after push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, assets

I started with a Rails app on Heroku that was working just fine, including pictures and CSS. When I tried to update the app and add pictures and some new links tied to an existing CSS class, none of the new assets worked. The strange part is that I changed some things about old links in the program and they acted as expected. It seemed at first like they just weren't precompiled so I ran `rake assets:precompile` both locally (and pushed) and on the server, but nothing changed. The new images still aren't showing up. To rule out a few other dumb mistakes, I have made sure that the image file exists and that it is a valid image tag by running it locally (everything is fine locally) and I am sure that my pushes to Git are working.

Comment: How large are the new files altogether?  Heroku recommends that you store non-core images (i.e. anything beyond logos, backgrounds, etc) on an external service such as S3: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

Comment: run `heroku logs` - do you get any errors?  if you look in your public folder, are all the images you need stored there?

Comment: When I run logs, I notice that all other images show a path of "assets/image-BIGHEXNUMBER.png" but the ones that aren't working show "images/image.png". I used the same method to produce the tags though. How do I look into the public folder?

Comment: however you would normally look at a file - in your terminal, with your text editor or through the gui.

Comment: it sounds like that it's just a misconfig of the asset pipeline. Have you tried running your application locally in production mode to see what happens?

Comment: Having similar problems -- some things are OK and some aren't. Static images uploaded as part of page (I'm using Refinery) are missing too.

Comment: Exactly what just happened to me right now.

Comment: Are you using the image_tag helper or a raw html img tag. I would recommend using the helper as rails would automatically add the big hex number in production mode. Also make sure you have turned on serve_static_assets = true in production.rb file and have installed the gem rails_serve_static_assets gem

Answer (score 1):

The problem you've got is that the images in the CSS are going to be static (image1.jpg), whereas in the pre-compiled production environment, they'll be called (image-05d983ce1986aa481e03729fca7a493a.jpg)

A good way to see if this is the case is to go onto `view source` -> `application-05d983ce1986aa481e03729fca7a493a.css` and look for the images your app needs. If they are static, that's the problem.

You may wish to try this to resolve it, but I feel it's a CSS issue (I have this problem too, so we're just seeing how to fix it):

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you `git add --all` before commiting

and try `heroku run rake assets:precompile` after pushing your commits